# In where shall I use isset() and !empty()

Tags: php, isset

I read somewhere that the `isset()` function treats an empty string as `TRUE`, therefore `isset()` is not an effective way to validate text inputs and text boxes from a HTML form.

So you can use `empty()` to check that a user typed something.

1. Is it true that the `isset()` function treats an empty string as `TRUE`?
2. Then in which situations should I use `isset()`? Should I always use `!empty()` to check if there is something?

For example instead of

```
if(isset($_GET['gender']))...
```

Using this

```
if(!empty($_GET['gender']))...
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

isset() checks if a variable has a
value, including `False`, `0` or empty
string, but not including NULL. Returns TRUE
if var exists and is not NULL; FALSE otherwise.

empty() does a reverse to what `isset` does (i.e. `!isset()`) and an additional check, as to whether a value is "empty" which includes an empty string, 0, NULL, false, or empty array or object
False. Returns FALSE if var is set and has a non-empty and non-zero value. TRUE otherwise

Comment: FTA: From the Article

Comment: `empty()` also returns true for an empty array.

Comment: Even tho `empty()` returns TRUE for 0, it's not a good idea to use this operator for math in case "0" is accidentally a string. This can be dangerous. Instead, use basic `>`, `<` and `==` operators and convert variables using `intval()` or `floatval()`.

Answer (score 41):

In the most general way :

- [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) tests if a variable (or an element of an array, or a property of an object) **exists** (and is not null)
- [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) tests if a variable is either not set or contains an empty-like value.

To answer **question 1** :

```
$str = '';
var_dump(isset($str));
```

gives

```
boolean true
```

Because the variable `$str` exists.

And **question 2** :

You should use `isset` to determine whether a variable **exists**; for instance, if you are getting some data as an array, you might need to check if a key is set in that array (and its value is not null).

Think about `$_GET` / `$_POST`, for instance.

If you want to know whether a variable exists **and** not "empty", that is the job of `empty`.

Answer (score 12):

[`isset`](http://docs.php.net/isset) is intended to be used only for variables and not just values, so `isset("foobar")` will raise an error. As of PHP 5.5, [`empty`](http://docs.php.net/empty) supports both variables and expressions.

So your first question should rather be if `isset` returns *true* for a variable that holds an empty string. And the answer is:

```
$var = "";
var_dump(isset($var));
```

The [type comparison tables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in PHP’s manual is quite handy for such questions.

`isset` basically checks if a variable has any value other than *null* since non-existing variables have always the value *null*. `empty` is kind of the counter part to `isset` but does also treat the integer value `0` and the string value `"0"` as empty. (Again, take a look at the [type comparison tables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).)

Comment: Note that [`empty()`](http://de2.php.net/empty) also "supports expressions, rather than only variables" as of PHP 5.5.0.

Answer (score 12):

Neither is a good way to check for valid input.

- `isset()` is not sufficient because – as has been noted already – it considers an empty string to be a valid value.
- `! empty()` is not sufficient either because it rejects '0', which could be a valid value.

Using `isset()` combined with an equality check against an empty string is the bare minimum that you need to verify that an incoming parameter has a value without creating false negatives:

```
if( isset($_GET['gender']) and ($_GET['gender'] !== '') )
{
  ...
}
```

But by "bare minimum", I mean exactly that.  All the above code does is determine whether there is some value for `$_GET['gender']`.  It does **not** determine whether the value for `$_GET['gender']` is *valid* (e.g., one of `("Male", "Female",` [`"FileNotFound"`](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)`)`).

For that, see [Josh Davis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219842/212218).

Comment: Because you are using a loose comparison, your suggested snippet will give false positives when handling a zero-ish/falsey non-string value.  https://3v4l.org/aIWqA

Answer (score 10):

If you have a $_POST['param'] and assume it's string type then

```
isset($_POST['param']) && $_POST['param'] != ''
```

is identical to

```
!empty($_POST['param'])
```

Answer (score 6):

isset() vs empty() vs is_null()

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When and how to use:

1. isset()

**True** for 0, 1, empty string, a string containing a value, true, false

**False** undefined variable for null

e.g

```
$status = 0
if (isset($status)) // True
$status = null 
if (isset($status)) // False
```

2. Empty

**False** for 1, a string containing a value, true

**True** for undefined value, null, empty string, 0, false
e.g

```
$status = 0
if(empty($status)) // true
$status = 1
if(empty($status)) // False
```

Answer (score 4):

> isset() is not an effective way to validate text inputs and text boxes from a HTML form

You can rewrite that as *"isset() is not a way to validate input."* To validate input, use PHP's [filter extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php). `filter_has_var()` will tell you whether the variable exists while `filter_input()` will actually filter and/or sanitize the input.

Note that you don't have to use `filter_has_var()` prior to `filter_input()` and if you ask for a variable that is not set, `filter_input()` will simply return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

```
isset($variable) === (@$variable !== null)
empty($variable) === (@$variable == false)
```

Answer (score 2):

isset is used to determine if an instance of something exists that is, if a variable has been instantiated... it is not concerned with the value of the parameter...

Pascal MARTIN... +1
...

empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist... therefore, isset() is preferred when testing for the existence of a variable when you intend to modify it...

Answer (score 2):

isset() is used to check if the variable is set with the value or not and Empty() is used to check if a given variable is empty or not.

isset() returns true when the variable is not null whereas Empty() returns true if the variable is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a quick way to check if a variable has any content in it. None of the answers here provided a full solution, so here it is:

---

It's enough to check if the input is `''` or `null`, because:

Request URL `.../test.php?var=` results in `$_GET['var'] = ''`

Request URL `.../test.php` results in `$_GET['var'] = null`

---

`isset()` returns `false` only when the variable exists and is not set to `null`, so if you use it you'll get `true` for empty strings (`''`).

`empty()` considers both `null` and `''` empty, but it also considers `'0'` empty, which is a problem in some use cases.

If you want to treat `'0'` as empty, then use `empty()`. Otherwise use the following check:

`$var .'' !== ''` evaluates to `false` only for the following inputs:

- `''`
- `null`
- `false`

I use the following check to also filter out strings with only spaces and line breaks:

```
function hasContent($var){
    return trim($var .'') !== '';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `empty` is enough:

```
if(!empty($variable)){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Additionally, if you want an integer value it might also be worth checking that `intval($variable) !== FALSE`.

Comment: Also, intval() never returns FALSE.

Comment: its NOT enough since '0' is a valid string but not for `empty`... `isset`/`filter_has_var` must be used to check if var exist.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following to avoid notices, this checks if the var it's declarated on GET or POST and with the @ prefix you can safely check if is not empty and avoid the notice if the var is not set:

```
if( isset($_GET['var']) && @$_GET['var']!='' ){
    //Is not empty, do something
}
```

Comment: The "stfu operator" (`@`) should not be encouraged and it is not necessary for your snippet.  This is not a good answer.  You are doing a loose comparison.  You may as well use `!empty()`.

Comment: Ooo man... This is great for the bad coding example. `@` will give you in the trouble with debugging, page impact is slower and you still can have `error_log` over 1GB in one moment. Just be smart and use `!empty()`, `!is_null()` or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $var = '';
// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if ( empty($var) ) {
echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}
// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if ( isset($var) ) {
 echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
    }
```

Source: Php.net

Answer (score -1):

isset() tests if a variable is set and not null:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

empty() can return true when the variable is set to certain values:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
<?php

$the_var = 0;

if (isset($the_var)) {
  echo "set";
} else {
  echo "not set";
}

echo "\n";

if (empty($the_var)) {
  echo "empty";
} else {
  echo "not empty";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**!empty** will do the trick. if you need only to check data exists or not then use **isset** other **empty** can handle other validations

```
<?php
$array = [ "name_new" => "print me"];

if (!empty($array['name'])){
   echo $array['name'];
}

//output : {nothing}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$array2 = [ "name" => NULL];

if (!empty($array2['name'])){
   echo $array2['name'];
}

//output : {nothing}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$array3 = [ "name" => ""];

if (!empty($array3['name'])){
   echo $array3['name'];
}

//output : {nothing}  

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$array4 = [1,2];

if (!empty($array4['name'])){
   echo $array4['name'];
}

//output : {nothing}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$array5 = [];

if (!empty($array5['name'])){
   echo $array5['name'];
}

//output : {nothing}
```

?>

Answer (score -1):

Please consider behavior may change on different PHP versions

From documentation

isset() Returns TRUE if var exists and has any value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

empty() does not exist or if its value equals FALSE
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

(empty($x) == (!isset($x) || !$x)) // returns true;

(!empty($x) == (isset($x) && $x)) // returns true;

Answer (score -1):

When in doubt, use this one to check your `Value` and to clear your head on the difference between `isset` and `empty`.

```
if(empty($yourVal)) {
  echo "YES empty - $yourVal"; // no result
}
if(!empty($yourVal)) {
  echo "<P>NOT !empty- $yourVal"; // result
}
if(isset($yourVal)) {
  echo "<P>YES isset - $yourVal";  // found yourVal, but result can still be none - yourVal is set without value
}
if(!isset($yourVal)) {
  echo "<P>NO !isset - $yourVal"; // $yourVal is not set, therefore no result
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following use for the two php constructs will help you choose the best fit in your case.

**Short story**

**`empty`** checks if the variable is set/defined and if it is it checks it for `null,false, "", 0`.

**`isset`** just checks if is it set, it could be anything not `null`

**Long story**

The `isset` verifies if a variable has been defined and holds any value, the value could be anything not null.

On the other hand, `empty` not only checks if the variable is set but also examines if it contains a value that is considered "empty," such as `null`, an empty string `''`,`false`, or `0`.