# How can I use PHP's isset() in addition to empty()?

Tags: php, isset

How would I add isset() and keep the empty() on my code below?

```
$pagesize = (!empty($_GET['pagesize'])) ? $_GET['pagesize'] : 20;
```

UPDATE:

I am just wanting to make sure php doesn't produce any notices or warnings

Comment: see this question's answers for more explanation about isset and empty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219542/in-where-shall-i-use-isset-and-empty

Comment: You don't have to add `isset`. `empty` will evaluate to true if the variable has not been set.

Comment: But won't empty still allow php's notices to show if the variable is not set or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why check both isset() and !empty()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$pagesize = (isset($_GET['pagesize']) && !empty($_GET['pagesize'])) ? 
                $_GET['pagesize'] :
                20;
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

**EDIT:**
To be complete, [empty](https://www.php.net/empty) already checks if something is set, so you don't need to use isset() as well.
I would also caution against using this code if it is going directly into a query or something similar. Consider using [intval](http://ca.php.net/intval), [is_numeric](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and similar functions.

Comment: that's quite redundant since `empty` checks if a value is set

Comment: I know, but I'm answering the question with the given information. Such a thing is dangerous anyways since it's possible to be set and not empty but still contain malicious code or unexpected data. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @nickf That's not true.  There are times when isset and empty can and should be used together.  It's true that empty returns true if a variable is not set, BUT not every variable that isset is empty.  Using isset and !empty is a good way to determine that a variable is set AND contains a usable value.

Comment: @Nilpo I think you got it backwards.  `! empty($var) and isset($var)` is redundant because there is no possible value (or lack thereof) for `$var` that would  cause `! empty($var)` to return `true` while causing `isset($var)` to return `false` (and if `! empty($var)` is `false`, then the conditional short-circuits, and `isset($var)` is not evaluated).  The only way the two would not be redundant is if you wanted to check if `empty($var) and isset($var)`, which is the same as (but IMnsHO more confusing than) `empty($var) and ! is_null($var)`.

Comment: @Nilpo is right the following article does an excellent job of describing the subtle differences. http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after here. `isset` will check if a value has been set and return true if it has. `empty` will check if a value *hasn't* been set OR if it equates to false (eg: `0, "", null`) and return true if it does.

I can't see why you'd need to combine the two. To rewrite your example *without* `empty`, you'd do this:

```
$pagesize = isset($_GET['pagesize']) && $_GET['pagesize']
          ? $_GET['pagesize']
          : 20;
```