# PHP isset() vs !empty()

Tags: php, isset

The problem is when I use

```
$fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : 'sample';
die($fname);
```

in PHP side after form submission with filled fname field getting output exactly what I filled, after submission with unfilled fname input field, getting output ABSOLUTELY NOTHING. Used code `!empty` instead

```
$fname = !empty($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : 'sample';
die($fname);
```

after submission with unfilled fname input field, getting output `sample`.

Comment: others may wish to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219542/in-where-shall-i-use-isset-and-empty?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the 'fname' variable is sent anyway, it's just empty but sent!

Try changing your form method from POST to GET and you'll see by yourself.

Answer (score 8):

`isset()` just checks whether the variable is `NULL` or not and won't throw an E_NOTICE error if you accessed an undefined index in an array (unlike `is_null()`).

It **does not** check whether the variable is containing an empty string!

Comment: One might expect `is_null()` to check if it's null or not and `isset()` to check whether it is set at all. Sadly, though, your description is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

This seems completely expected to me.

You submitted a form with an element called `fname`, so even though it was empty it was still set.

Meaning `isset` evaluates to true, hence you output nothing if you submit with nothing

Answer (score 2):

What is your question?

Using `isset()` on `$_POST['key']` will return `true` in this circumstance, because the variable itself has been set and passed through from the form. Because you're assigning the value of `$_POST['fname']` to the `$fname` variable, the value will always been assigned, even if it's empty.

`empty()` will return false if there is no assignment to that variable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems right to me. It happens that when input field is sent empty, it'll be *empty* in `$_POST` array, *not* `NULL`.

```
$_POST['fname'] = "";
isset($_POST['fname']) == true;

$_POST['fname'] = "";
!empty($_POST['fname']) == false;
```

What you could do is use `array_key_exists` to check it is in `$_POST` array instead of `isset`:

```
$_POST['fname'] = "";
array_key_exists('fname', $_POST) == true; // independent of its value
```