# Undefined offset notice in loop

Tags: php, loops, undefined, offset

I'm using a script to create additional form rows.
It loops the $i number for certain text fields
When I run this script, the offset is undefined because it doesn't exsist.
I need to use the if(isset()) function, but I am unsure how I would place it in the code.
Can anyone help?

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {

    if ($text['length'][$i] == "") $text['length'][$i] = "0";
    if ($text['bredth'][$i] == "") $text['bredth'][$i] = "0";
    if ($text['height'][$i] == "") $text['height'][$i] = "0";
    if ($text['weight'][$i] == "") $text['weight'][$i] = "0.00";
```

All the lines starting with 'if' show the notice:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\newparcelscript.php on line 41

SOLVED
Infact i did not require and 'if' stament at all, because the creation of the rows and the setting of the values are run together.

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {

   $text['length'][$i] = "0";
   $text['breadth'][$i] = "0";
   $text['height'][$i] = "0";
   $text['weight'][$i] = "0.00";
```

Comment: I suggest to try $text[$i]['weight']

Comment: glad i could help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think testing for `empty()` is what you're looking for here.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    if(empty($text['length'][$i]) === TRUE) $text['length'][$i] = 0;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you're trying to do here, I either suggest you use one of the following isset/empty combinations

```
if (isset($text['length'][$i]) == false or empty($text['length'][$i]) == true)

if (isset($text['length'][$i]) == true and empty($text['length'][$i]) == true)
```

The error is most likely coming from testing against a index that doesn't exist: *if($text['length'][$i] == "")*

Comment: Solved, I was creating those rows, but the code for creating and setting values are run simultaneously, so actually i didn't need an 'if' statement at all

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, if you need to insert values for undefined fields, use `empty()`.

`empty()` returns TRUE if the values is a empty string, while `!isset()` will return FALSE.
There are many questions about this, for example [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219542/in-where-shall-i-use-isset-and-empty).

Something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    if (empty($text['length'][$i])) $text['length'][$i] = "0";
    if (empty($text['bredth'][$i])) $text['bredth'][$i] = "0";
    if (empty($text['height'][$i])) $text['height'][$i] = "0";
    if (empty($text['weight'][$i])) $text['weight'][$i] = "0.00";
}
```