# Check empty value and output default value in Laravel view / blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Smarty Templates I can simply check a value in my case an array and if empty I can output a default value like this:

```
{$smarty.session.foo['bar']|default:"empty"}
```

How can I simply do the same in laravel blade without nested @if statements?

```
@if(session()->has('foo'))
    @if( ! empty( session('foo')->bar ) )
        {{ session('foo')->bar }}
    @else
       empty
    @endif
@endif
```

How can I do this shorthand?

Comment: figure out the value you want BEFORE sending to the view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo a default value if value not set blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023480/how-to-echo-a-default-value-if-value-not-set-blade)

Comment: I'm totally not a fan of logic in views. Everything should be figured out prior to being sent to the view. The ideal view only has loops and echoes.

Comment: @delboy1978uk for business logic I'd agree, but checking if something is empty seems perfectly fine for a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade has a built  in structure for this using `OR`.

```
{{ session('foo')->bar OR 'empty' }}
```

Blade also accepts regular PHP, so  you can use the elvis operator to skip any false value:

```
{{ session('foo')->bar ?: 'empty' }}
```

Or the null-coalescing operator to skip null values (PHP7+).

```
{{ session('foo')->bar ?? 'empty' }}
```

For all of these though, `session('foo')` would still need to return an object.

Comment: And what if is not an Object? I think that's my main Issue. Some Sessions are only set in special cases and they can by empty.

Comment: Null-coalescing should work with a non-object, but the other two examples won't I believe.  They would issue a notice of accessing a property on a non-object.