# Trapping "Trying to get property of non-object" in blade templats

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-blade

i'm debugging a laravel project, and there are many instances where the developer simply dropped double mustaches into the blade templates referencing object properties, without first checking if those relations exist.

example

```
{{$category->name}}

<small>{{$category->parent->name}}</small>
```

Is there a built in way in laravel to just silently fail if for example $category is not set, or $category->parent is not set, without resorting to something along these lines...

```
@if (isset($category))
   {{$category->name}}
@endif

@if (isset($main_category->parent))
    @if($main_category->parent != null)
        <small>{{$main_category->parent->name}}</small>
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you get the value for the parent property ?

Comment: I don't know Blade that well anymore, but can you try: `{{$category->name ?? ''}}` and see if that works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023480/how-to-echo-a-default-value-if-value-not-set-blade

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo a default value if value not set blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023480/how-to-echo-a-default-value-if-value-not-set-blade)

Comment: You can do it as easily as `if($main_category->parent)`, which will check for the existing relationship. It's a bit harder for `$category`, since the variable may or may not exist, so the first option is best

Comment: Are you sure you want to go this way? For the second example, this would mean printing an empty `<small>` tag - I would vote to fix the errors instead of hiding them

Comment: I am leaning in this direction. in certain cases i may want to simply suppress the error. I am thinking this is going to be long hard trek through the mud to get this cleaned up. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Suppressing errors is never a good solution... You need to handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way.

```
{{ $category->name ?? '' }}
// or
{{ $category->name or '' }} // for older version of laravel
```

Comment: this works fine if you are using a recent version of php, if you are using an older one, you will need to use the full syntax ( condition ? if-true : if-false)

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to hide error you get,

```
{{ @$category }}
```

`@` will suppress error for undefined or unset variables.

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
>   prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
>   generated by that expression will be ignored.

Here is official php documentation for [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: in terms of what i asked this is the cleanest looking solution i think... unless there's a way to make it do that by default in the models or something. thank you.