# Laravel blade variable default value issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blade master view in Laravel which contains the code `{{$home or ''}}`. My server is using PHP 7.1, Nginx. I migrated the code to another server with cPanel, just copied the whole contents and database and setup everything. The server to which I migrated the code runs Litespeed and Php 7.3. The same code works on server running nginx but not the newly migrated server. When I browse the page, I get `Undefined variable: home`. How can it run on nginx and not when using Litespeed. I'm new to litespeed and I haven't configured anything specific to laravel. Can someone please help to get this working.

Edit 1:
based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023480/how-to-echo-a-default-value-if-value-not-set-blade), this syntax doesn't work on Laravel 5.7 and above but I'm using 5.8 and it works fine at the moment on old server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
{{$home ?? ''}}
```

Comment: This works, I'm however not able to understand this behavior. Why does it work on PHP7.1+Nginx while not on PHP7.1+Litespeed