# How to use if conditions with php to evaluate false or true conditions of a submitted button?

Tags: php, if-statement, post, submit, isset

I'm using a standard form in combination with two if constructs and I am not sure if the syntax are ok. Is there a better way to refactor the following code?

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
 
   }

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
 
   }


<form class="mt20" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="speichern">

</form>
```

Pressing the submit button the site should be reloaded and the code within the `if(!isset( ...` bracket should not be executed. For hundreds of users the code is not executed. But there is one user where the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

[This should help you explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219542/in-where-shall-i-use-isset-and-empty)

Also if possible just do a if/else conditional instead of doing two checks which is redundant and confusing. I think that one user might be artificially manipulating the data and passing in NULL thus triggering the !isset

Answer (score -2):

You can do as:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

} else {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    }   
}
```

Comment: the code inside the if (!isset  does not executes upon submit

Comment: Use elseif{} instead