# How to benchmark code to see which runs faster

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Can anyone tell me which is faster, recommended and takes less memory in huge operations in php file. I think its DateInterval PID. Any experienced developer?

Comment: It definitely won't be noticeable to the naked eye, so put each method in a loop of a million iterations, and calculate the time taken by each version. `microtime(true)` will return the current time at a high enough degree of accuracy for this.

Comment: @delboy1978uk change my question, Good!. Now in future no one can search the speed of 'PID' vs '+1 day' in future

Comment: Your question would have been seriously downvoted had it been left the way it was.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219542/in-where-shall-i-use-isset-and-empty same type of question but no one bet an eye.

Comment: Looks like DateInterval is faster, see below

Comment: _...you don't have to be so rude_ I wasn't! This is just a matter of perception ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To benchmark code, you can use `microtime()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

```
<?php

echo 'modify: ';
$time = microtime(1);
for ($x = 0; $x < 10000; $x++) {
    $datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
    $datetime->modify('+1 day');
}
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$end = microtime(1);
$time = $end - $time;
echo $time . "\n";

echo 'interval: ';
$time = microtime(1);
for ($x = 0; $x < 10000; $x++) {
    $datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
    $datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
$end = microtime(1);
$time = $end - $time;
echo $time . "\n";
```

This outputs :

```
modify: 0.039623975753784 
interval: 0.036103963851929
```

As you can see, after performing the calculation 10,000 times on each, DateInterval is the faster code. However, this is what I would call a microoptimisation! There isn't much difference!

See it working here https://3v4l.org/pCecn

Comment: It seems DateInterval is slower on php 5.6

Comment: Indeed that does seem to be the case for any version below `5.6.30`. 5.6 is due to be EOL at the end of the year! I suggest if you are using it, that you upgrade! Please check here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Answer (score -2):

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This is faster because, in DateInterval, you will need to use interval specification which is hard to read.