# isset() and empty() - what to use

Tags: php

Could you help me to improve my coding style?:) In some tasks I need to check - is variable empty or contains something. To solve this task, I usually do the following.

Check - is this variable set or not? If it's set - I check - it's empty or not?

```
<?php
    $var = '23';
    if (isset($var)&&!empty($var)){
        echo 'not empty';
    }else{
        echo 'is not set or empty';
    }
?>
```

And I have a question - should I use isset() before empty() - is it necessary? TIA!

Comment: empty is      !isset($var) || $var == false

Comment: in my oppinion empty() is a horrific development of PHP.
As it consideres "0" in any forms as "empty" you may fall into bad traps costing lots of debugging time.
I'd say: avoid at all cost and just write the logic yourself

Answer (score 158, accepted):

It depends what you are looking for, if you are just looking to see if it is empty just use `empty` as it checks whether it is set as well, if you want to know whether something is set or not use `isset`.

`Empty` checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc

`Isset` just checks if is it set, it could be anything not null

With `empty`, the following things are considered empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

As mentioned in the comments the lack of warning is also important with empty()

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/empty) says

> empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no **warning is
>   generated when the variable is not set**.

Regarding isset

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/isset) says

> isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL

---

Your code would be fine as:

```
<?php
    $var = '23';
    if (!empty($var)){
        echo 'not empty';
    }else{
        echo 'is not set or empty';
    }
?>
```

---

For example:

```
$var = "";

if(empty($var)) // true because "" is considered empty
 {...}
if(isset($var)) //true because var is set 
 {...}

if(empty($otherVar)) //true because $otherVar is null
 {...}
if(isset($otherVar)) //false because $otherVar is not set 
 {...}
```

Comment: It's mean - in the code above I check is variable set or not twice?:)

Comment: Just check whether it is empty, php won't throw an error if this is not the case.

Comment: You are omitting the biggest point of `empty`: It doesn't throw a warning when the tested variable does not exist. That's the whole point of this function, otherwise it's identical to `== false`.

Comment: So, the fact in manual that "no warning is generated when the variable is not set" confused me. No warning doesn't mean that I will not have troubles in the code below. Now it's clear for me. Thx alot!

Comment: *"isset just checks if is it set, it could still be null"* That's not true: `isset` on a null (and existing) variable will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 14):

In your particular case: `if ($var)`.

You need to use `isset` if you don't know *whether the variable exists* or not. Since you declared it on the very first line though, you know it exists, hence you don't need to, nay, *should not* use `isset`.

The same goes for `empty`, only that `empty` also combines a check for the *truthiness* of the value. `empty` is equivalent to `!isset($var) || !$var` and `!empty` is equivalent to `isset($var) && $var`, or `isset($var) && $var == true`.

If you only want to test a variable that *should exist* for *truthiness*, `if ($var)` is perfectly adequate and to the point.

Comment: This one explains much much better. If we get comparison for all other cases like this `!empty is equivalent to isset($var) && $var`, it would be awesome. Thanks @deceze

Answer (score 7):

You can just use empty() - as seen in [the documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), it will return false if the variable has no value.

An example on that same page:

```
<?php
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
?>
```

You can use isset if you just want to know if it is not NULL. Otherwise it seems empty() is just fine to use alone.

Comment: Explanation for the down vote? He's not asking if they are the same, he's asking if he needs to check isset before checking empty.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "use isset if you want to know it is not null" is not correct: `$var = null; isset( $var ) == true`.

Comment: From the PHP5/4 Manual: isset() - "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL." http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2):

Here are the outputs of `isset()` and `empty()` for the 4 possibilities: undeclared, null, false and true.

```
$a=null;
$b=false;
$c=true;

var_dump(array(isset($z1),isset($a),isset($b),isset($c)),true); //$z1 previously undeclared
var_dump(array(empty($z2),empty($a),empty($b),empty($c)),true); //$z2 previously undeclared

//array(4) { [0]=> bool(false) [1]=> bool(false) [2]=> bool(true) [3]=> bool(true) } 
//array(4) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> bool(true) [3]=> bool(false) }
```

You'll notice that all the 'isset' results are opposite of the 'empty' results *except* for case `$b=false`. All the values (except null which isn't a value but a non-value) that evaluate to false will return true when tested for by `isset` and false when tested by 'empty'.

So use `isset()` when you're concerned about the existence of a variable.  And use `empty` when you're testing for true or false. If the actual type of emptiness matters, use `is_null` and `===0`, `===false`, `===''`.

Answer (score 1):

Empty returns true if the var is not set. But isset returns true even if the var is not empty.

Comment: This is a somewhat misleading and incomplete answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
$var = 'abcdef';
if(isset($var))
{
   if (strlen($var) > 0);
   {
      //do something, string length greater than zero
   }
   else
   {
     //do something else, string length 0 or less
   }
}
```

This is a simple example. Hope it helps.

edit: added `isset` in the event a variable isn't defined like above, it would cause an error, checking to see if its first set at the least will help remove some headache down the road.

Comment: `strlen` *under* zero? I wanna see that string.

Comment: @deceze Just a rough example :) OK use =0 not <0