# Check if array key exists and is truthy in same command?

Tags: php, web, idioms

In JavaScript, one can check `myObject.key` to see wether the value is there (not undefined) *and* truthy.

```
if (myObject.key) ...
```

Is there a PHP equivalent? Or do I have to keep writing code such as `isset(my_array['key']) && my_array['key']` to acheive the desired result? I feel it violates DRY and looks ugly.

Comment: [`!empty(my_array['key'])` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?

Comment: Just to put my two cents in: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/. Additionally, a similar [question has been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty) here on SO as well.

Comment: @Sean, write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Sean Looks awesome. `empty` checks for 'falsyness', so negating it checks for 'truthyness', am I right? And this won't raise a notice if the key is not set?

Comment: @GinoPane I am more inclined to close a duplicate of [isset vs empty vs is_null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375833/isset-vs-empty-vs-is-null) then to provide an answer.

Comment: @AvivCohn yes, per the docs -  [`empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are three "levels" of checking in php:

1. array_key_exists($key, $array) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Checks if a key exists in an array. Returns true even if the value is null

2. isset($array[$key]) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Check if a key exists and is not null - Returns true if the value exists and is not null, but it can be bool(false), int(0), string "" and so on.

3. !empty($array[$key]) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Check if a key exists and is truthy, returns false for bool(false), int(0), non-existant keys and null, but true for bool(true), int(1), int(-1), string with length > 0 and so on. Actually the function it is empty(), but often used negated, too. This should be what you are searching for.

Comment: Exactly, something to check for existence and truthyness. Thanks :) will accept.

Comment: Empty is your best option here, because it will not complain if you pass it non-existant keys.

Comment: #2 is incorrect. `isset` returns false if the value is `null`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: @Sean the bean: exactly what I said, "isset() returns true If key exists and is not null" => false if key does not exist, false if value is null, but true if it is e.g. 0, "", false, []

Comment: @clemens321 Ah, right you are. I just got mixed up because of the indentation.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the error suppression operator @:

```
if (@$_GET['fantasyvar']) {
    //$_GET['fantasyvar'] is set and truthy
}
```

Note: it's not good style and will make debugging more difficult for you.