# How to differentiate a value is zero or NULL in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, null, zero

I have a variable e.g `$moon`

In some cases its value is

```
$moon=0;
```

In other cases its value is

```
$moon=NULL;
```

Now in if clause **how can i differentiate between these values?**

My code is

```
if($moon==0 && !empty($moon)){
    echo "its zero";        
}else{
    echo "its null";
}
```

**it always shows "its zero"**

I also tried

```
if($moon==0 && $moon!=NULL){
    echo "its zero";        
}else{
    echo "its null";
}
```

Comment: try $moon === 0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to check for null use :

```
if (is_null($moon))
```

to check for integer 0 use:

```
if ($moon === 0)
```

to check for integer 0 or string "0"

```
if ($moon == '0')
```

I have to add that php will consider any string equals with number 0 when using "==":

```
$moon = "asd";

if ($moon == 0) // will be true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution (using `is_null` and `===`):

```
if (is_null($moon)) {
    echo "its null";
} elseif ($moon === 0) {
   echo "its zero"; 
} elseif ($moon == 0) {
   echo "its zero (string)";
} else {
   echo "another value";
}
```

You can use the function [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php).

**explanation using `is_null`:**

```
$val1 = NULL;
$val2 = 0;
var_dump(is_null($val1)); //true
var_dump(is_null($val2)); //false
```

**explanation using `===`:**

```
$val1 = NULL;
$val2 = 0;
var_dump($val1 === 0); //false
var_dump($val2 === 0); //true
```

> **Demo:** https://ideone.com/TpPQQi

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use three equal to see if the given value is identical so

```
$moon = 0;
if($moon === 0) {
    echo 'its zero';
} else {
    echo 'is null';
}
```

You can check more about comparison operators [**here**](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP's language construct `isset()` will report `true` to let you know if the value is NOT `null`. You can also use `is_null()`, but `isset()` tends to be reported as being faster.

```
if (isset($var)) {
    echo 'It is something.';
} else {
    echo 'It is nothing.';
}
```

or

```
if (!is_null($var)) {
    echo 'It is something.';
} else {
    echo 'It is nothing.';
}
```

or

```
if ($var !== null)) {
    echo 'It is something.';
} else {
    echo 'It is nothing.';
}
```

Comment: For those who use `isset` to check for `null`: Keep in mind that [`isset` is **not** the same as `is_null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375833/isset-vs-empty-vs-is-null).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you can use the `is_null()` function.

You can use this function in conjunction with the `!` operator in your `if()` statement as follows:

```
if( $moon==0 && !is_null($moon) ){
    echo "its zero";        
}else{
    echo "its null";
}
```