# Validation using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form like this in my PHP document:

```
<form id="biddingform" name="biddingform" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkBidding()" action="makebid.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table class="biddingtable">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="bidlabel"><input type="hidden" id="itemidhidden" name="itemidhidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['itemid']; ?>></td>
    <td class="bidprice">$<input class="itembidlengthfield" id="itembidprice" name="itembidprice" type="number" min="<?php echo $minprice; ?>" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $minprice; ?>" required></td>
    <td class="bidbutton"><input class="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Make bid" type="submit"></td>
    <td id="biderrormsg" class="biderrormsg"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

My jQuery AJAX call looks like this (note that both the variables are retrieved correctly):

```
function checkBidding()
{
    var itembidprice = document.getElementById("itembidprice").value;
    var itemid = document.getElementById("itemidhidden").value;

    $.post('biddingvalidation.php', { bidprice: itembidprice, id: itemid }, function(result) {
        window.alert(result);
            if (result != "")
            {
                $('#biderrormsg').html(result);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

And lastly my biddingvalidation.php looks like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['bidprice']) && isset($_REQUEST['id'])) 
    {
        require 'includes/dbfunctions.php';
        $itembidprice = $_REQUEST['bidprice'];
        $itemid = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $biddingsql = "SELECT MAX(amount) AS amount FROM `bidding` WHERE itemid='$itemid'";
        $result = db_query($biddingsql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $maxbid = $row['amount'];
        }

        if ($itembidprice <= $maxbid)
        {
            echo "Bid too low";
        }  else {
            echo "";
        }


    } else {
        echo "Error, try again";
    }


    ?>
```

I have done excessive testing but I just can't figure out why it is not working as intended. I open two browsers and test this as seen in the picture, the left side of the picture is my chrome browser, and the right one is my firefox browser. (i am logged in as 2 different users on the website):
[image: problems]

As can be seen from the picture, on chrome I put a new bid at 220$ and since I have not yet refreshed my firefox the (ex)current highest bid is still 200$ there. so i try to bid for example 210$ on firefox, instead of giving me any of the echoed errors as stated in the biddingvalidation.php file it just submits the form and does nothing (because of other extra checks in the background right before mysql insertion). However I need the echoed error messages to appear in this kind of situation, what am I doing wrong why they are not appearing?

**EDIT:** 
I just simply try to show every single variable with window.alert, and I noticed that it does not even get a result anymore, the itembidprice & itemid are correctly shown, and from that point on I don't even get the first window.alert(result) anymore

```
function checkBidding()
{
        var itembidprice = document.getElementById("itembidprice").value;
        var itemid = document.getElementById("itemidhidden").value;
        window.alert(itembidprice);
        window.alert(itemid);

        $.post('biddingvalidation.php', { bidprice: itembidprice, id: itemid }, function(result) {
            window.alert(result);
                if (result != "")
                {
                    window.alert(result);
                    window.alert("ja");
                    $('#biderrormsg').html(result);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    window.alert(result);
                    window.alert("nee");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I can't see itemidhidden

Comment: Open up your console, is there an error? As @kimbarcelona mentioned, in the HTML markup you provided there is no `itemidhidden` which your javascript is searching for

Comment: Sorry it is there. <input type="hidden" id="itemidhidden" name="itemidhidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['itemid']; ?>> , i edited my question. there are no errors in the console @Feek

Comment: I did notice that when I change the condition in the biddingvalidation.php to ($itembidprice >= $maxbid) that I do get the error message correctly (but obviously the condition is wrong and the error message is not appropriate). It just won't let me pass through the form submission when result = ""

Comment: All the code is working flawlessly, I just want to do this validation check because right now if the user submits a value which is lower than the current bid the page just refreshes and there is no error message that his bid did not succeed, so i want to display with ajax the error message that his bid was too low and he has an 'outdated' version of the page

Answer (score 0):

First, i hve two possible fix:

1. There's no `itemhidden` element in your markup.

> var itemid = document.getElementById("itemidhidden").value; // itemid
>   = null

2. Second, bidprice and id are always present after ajax even if empty, i think you need [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for this not isset():

> ```
>  if(isset($_REQUEST['bidprice']) && isset($_REQUEST['id'])) 
>     {
> ```

should be:

> ```
> if(!empty($_REQUEST['bidprice']) && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])) 
>     {
> ```

I believe that on your current code, it's always true for isset so it won't do anything because there's no id.

Here's a better reason on why you need [!empty than isset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use)

Comment: I edited my question, the hidden element is there and is working as it should. However, no luck with the !empty, I did notice that when I change the condition in the biddingvalidation.php to ($itembidprice >= $maxbid) that I do get the error message correctly (but obviously the condition is wrong and the error message is not appropriate). It just won't let me pass through the form submission when result = ""

Comment: My formulation was probably off, I mean that if I put this if ($itembidprice >= $maxbid) { echo "Bid too low"; } that I do correctly get the 'bid too low' displayed in my form. however, the condition should be the other way around and it is not working like that :P I edited my main question with some debugging examples and the lack of output

Comment: I'm confused and lost. What is the real issue? Can you modify your question again and make it simplier?

Comment: The problem is that the $.post is not returning anything, it does not even go into the function (as the first window.alert is not popping up) thus i am unable to show an error message here

Comment: Is it reloading after you submit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58921/discussion-between-dennis-and-kimbarcelona).