# PHP IF ELSE issue, can not get correct answers

Tags: php, scope

I wrote php function for get weekend, this "**$data['projects']**" is not empty, but it is redirect to `$end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday'));`

```
function weekendignSet(){
     if(!empty($data['projects'])){
         $end = $data['projects'][0]->week_end_day;
      }else{
         if(!empty($_GET['week_ending'])){
             $end = $_GET['week_ending'];
         }else{
             $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday'));
         }
      }
      return $end;
}
```

What is the error? thank you

Comment: try to use `if(!isset($data['projects']))` and tell us how it went

Comment: @AresDraguna `!empty` will automatically check if the value is set.

Comment: `$data` is not in scope and will be always empty.

Comment: @AresDraguna Not working

Comment: @Fluffeh `!isset` will check if the `projects` is actually set... `!empty` just checks if there is a value in `projects`

Comment: @AresDraguna The first check of `empty` is whether the value is set - then it checks if it is empty. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7191642/1450077

Comment: @AresDraguna So you're saying that `empty($data['projects'])` returns `false` if `$data['projects']` is not set?

Comment: @Fluffeh I did not knew that empty checks if its set first... thank you for that link!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$data` to function then it will check in if() else you always goes in else condition try

```
function weekendignSet($data){
```

on calling :-

```
weekendignSet($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs an input paramater named "$data"

Answer (score 0):

Make the `$data` a global variable, or pass it into a function:

```
global $data;
$data = array();
function weekendignSet(){
     global $data;
     if(!empty($data['projects'])){
         $end = $data['projects'][0]->week_end_day;
      }else{
         if(!empty($_GET['week_ending'])){
             $end = $_GET['week_ending'];
         }else{
             $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday'));
         }
      }
      return $end;
}
```

or

```
$data = array();
function weekendignSet($data){
     if(!empty($data['projects'])){
         $end = $data['projects'][0]->week_end_day;
      }else{
         if(!empty($_GET['week_ending'])){
             $end = $_GET['week_ending'];
         }else{
             $end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday'));
         }
      }
      return $end;
}
weekendignSet($data);
```