# Why curl not work when use with if condition?

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I tried to use curl with if condition, It's not work.

```
if($_GET[test] != '')
{
    $fb = new FacebookDebugger();
    $fb->reload('http://www.example.com');

    class FacebookDebugger
    {
        public function reload($url)
        {
            $graph = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
            $post = 'id='.urlencode($url).'&scrape=true';
            return $this->send_post($graph, $post);
        }
        private function send_post($url, $post)
        {
            $r = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            $data = curl_exec($r);
            curl_close($r);
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

But when remove if condition, curl will be work good.

How can i do for using curl with if condition ?

Comment: Don't put the class inside the if-statement

Comment: `$_GET[test]` should most likely be quoted `$_GET['test']` - that would throw an undefined constant test notice.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. If so, tell us what that shows. If it shows as an undefined constant notice, then you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a function before initializing, try below code.

```
class FacebookDebugger
{
    public function reload($url)
    {
        $graph = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
        $post = 'id='.urlencode($url).'&scrape=true';
        return $this->send_post($graph, $post);
    }

    private function send_post($url, $post)
    {
        $r = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        $data = curl_exec($r);
        curl_close($r);
        return $data;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET[test]) && $_GET[test] != '') {
    $fb = new FacebookDebugger();
    $fb->reload('http://www.example.com');
}
```

Comment: OP: *"But when remove if condition, curl will be work good."* could also have something to do with `$_GET[test]` not being quoted.

Comment: Sidenote: `if (isset($_GET[test]) && $_GET[test] != '')` could be reduced to simply `if(!empty($_GET[test]))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Always use isset to check the existence of a certain variable. Trying to access $_GET[test] will also raise an E_Notice when there is no "test" variable defined. Checking with isset can avoid this.

Comment: I quote http://stackoverflow.com/a/7191642/ : *"Empty checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc"*.

Comment: and from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php I quote: *"No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false."* - However, in some special instances, you could be right.

Comment: I was checking the same manual. You are right.

Comment: Yeah, it's been debated before. However, and as I said earlier. There may be times where using both `isset()` and checking if an array equals something will be useful. I wasn't downgrading your answer ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: You're welcome Devendra, *cheers*