# default value of date inf form if not set

Tags: php, forms, date

so here is code:

```
echo "<label>";
echo "  <span>Data nuo: </span>";
echo "  <input id='data' name='data' type='date' pattern='(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))' title='Data ivesti tokiu formatu: 2016-01-01' >"; 
echo "  </label>";
```

ad then

```
$field3 = isset( $_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "";
echo $field3;
```

so when date is set, I get my chosed date printed, but if date is not set, i get nothing printed, question is, what is default value of date if date is not set? NULL? How to print "Date is not set" if date is not set?

```
if ($field3 == ????) {
echo "date is not set";
```

Comment: `$field3 = isset( $_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "Nothing printed";echo $field3;` Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: not really, it gives nothing printed if submit button is not pushed, after pushing it, it prints nothing...

Comment: You're probably looking for `if ( ! $field3 )` or `if ( empty( $field3 ) )`. You can use `isset( $_POST['data'] )` to see if the field was submitted in the form, but if it is empty, it will be an empty string. [Some details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use).

Comment: Just like any other `<input>` field -- the default value is an empty satring.

Answer (score 0):

Simply echo the expected data format :

```
$field3 = isset( $_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "YYYY-MM-DD";
echo $field3;
```

Comment: no, it`s not good, it wont print anything if i wont set any date in form

Comment: It should since when the code first run $_POST['data'] is not set so $field3 value will be "YYYY-MM-DD" when you echo it in the next line.

Comment: Actually, yes it prints, but before I press submit button, after button pressed, nothing is printed

Comment: Yeah my bad i misunderstand your question ^.^

Answer (score 0):

> if ($field3 == ????) {

Actually you can use `""` instead of `????`. But I suggset to do:

```
if (empty($field3)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
if empty($field3) {
    echo "date is not set";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php