# PHP Ternary Expression / If Statement

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm learning ternary expressions in PHP and was wondering if someone could verify that the following two blocks of code are the same as far as what is the outcome?

```
$caption = $_POST['caption'] == '' ? NULL : $_POST['caption'];
```

Is the above the same as the below?

```
if ( $_POST['caption'] == '' ) {
    $caption = NULL;
}
else {
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
}
```

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: Condition is okay. Make sure **caption** key is exist in $_POST. use empty function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes  they are same.

```
$vn = condition ? expression1:expression2;
```

is same as

```
if(condition) {
    $vn = expression1;
}
else {
   $vn = expression2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is okay. but make sure that you have `caption` key in `$_POST` array.

```
$caption = empty($_POST['caption']) ? NULL : $_POST['caption'];
```

OR

```
$caption = (isset($_POST['caption']) && $_POST['caption'] == '') ? $_POST['caption'] : NULL;
```

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) functions are useful in that case.

```
$a = '';
var_dump(isset($a));      // TRUE
var_dump(empty($a));      // TRUE
```

[isset() and empty() - what to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use)

Comment: Like this? $caption = isset($_POST['caption']) == '' ? NULL : $_POST['caption'];

Comment: Why would you need to check if $_POST['caption'] is set? If $_POST['caption'] = '' (empty string) doesn't that automatically mean it is set?

Comment: if caption key is **not exist** in $_POST array and if you write condition as **$_POST['caption'] == ''** then it will give you an **error**.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in my script and I still get the error: Notice: Undefined index: caption.

Comment: Write your condition this way:- $caption = (isset($_POST['caption']) && $_POST['caption'] == '') ? $_POST['caption'] : NULL;