# multilingual website in php $_GET error

Tags: php, session, get, multilingual

i am try to make a multilingual website following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLL-bAVqsc0) example.
i made a folder language and created 2 files the en.php and the gr.php.

here are my files

language/gr.php

```
<?php
$lang = array(
//nav bar
'nav1' => 'Αρχική',
'nav2' => 'Δυτική Αττική',
'nav3' => 'Εκδηλώσεις',
'nav4' => 'Σύλλογοι',
'nav5' => 'Καταστήματα'
);
?>
```

language/en.php

```
<?php
$lang = array(
//nav bar
'nav1' => 'Home',
'nav2' => 'West Attica',
'nav3' => 'News/Events',
'nav4' => 'Associations',
'nav5' => 'Stores'
 );
?>
```

and the ini.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$allowed_lang = array('gr', 'en');

if (isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed_lang) === true){
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}

include 'language/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';

 ?>
```

when i am try to run it i get this errors

> Notice: Undefined index: lang in /home/user/public_html/init.php on line 10
>   Warning: include(language/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/peerkavlos/public_html/init.php on line 10
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening 'language/.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/user/public_html/init.php on line 10

tried to echo the `$_GET['lang'];` but the results has no value

that means that the `$_GET['lang']` is empty

what am i missing guys?

Comment: fix the path and the rest should follow

Comment: What if there is no lang in $_GET ? I think you should provide an initial value to $_SESSION['lang']

Comment: so now both answers are right, which one should i accept as the right one?

Comment: hello Andreas and thanks for your answer. you are right, its working by setting a value  to $_SESSION['lang']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (!empty($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed_lang)) 
{
    # TRUE part
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    include 'language/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';
} 
else 
{
    # FALSE part
    echo "Selected Language Couldn't initialize"; 
    include 'language/en.php';
}
```

---

**Useful  links**

1. [PHP `in_array()` Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)
2. [PHP 5 Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)
3. [`isset()` and `empty()` - what to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use)

Comment: Hello Abdulla and thanks for your answer, its working like a charm!

Comment: This will not pull the lang from the session on subsequent page loads. I.e., if you request GR then it will give you GR on the first page and EN on the next.

Comment: @AlexHowansky its not page load. its language change only :P :P

Comment: "its language change only" Heh not likely on a page named `init.php`...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a default, so when the `_GET` variable is empty, you get an include on a file that doesn't exist. Maybe just hard code a default:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
if (isset($_GET['lang']) ... ) {
}
include 'language/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer alex both answers working like a charm!