# PHP: Receiving blank email

Tags: php

I used `isset()` function so that I will not receive the blank email. I can still receive blank emails.

Please see my code

Is `!empty()` better than `isset()` ?

What is the difference between the two?

Many Thanks

```html
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone'])){



$postcode = isset($_POST['postcode']) ? $_POST['postcode'] : "";
$name     = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$email    = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
$phone    = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : "";
$business = isset($_POST['business']) ? $_POST['business'] : "";

$to      = 'rme@btel.com';
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode('Message from BTelecom') . "?=";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
@$message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>' .


'Post Code: ' . strip_tags($postcode) . '<br/>' .
'Email: ' . strip_tags($email) . '<br/>' .
'Name: ' . strip_tags($name) . '<br/>' .
'Phone: ' . strip_tags($phone) . '<br/>' .
'Business: ' . strip_tags($business) . '' .

    '</body></html>';
    $actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Comment: `empty()` and `isset()` are not the same. Why the `@` before `$message`?

Comment: Hello @Mehdi . what do you mean by @?

Comment: I don't know how to explain further... read the code part I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @ suppresses the error and I don't see why you would want that

Comment: Hello @hungrykoala Is that Possible reason. why I'am receiving blank emails?

Comment: may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: many thanks to all your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP **empty** function just checks the blank value while on other side **isset** checks for variable existence.