# What's the difference between 'isset()' and '!empty()' in PHP?

Tags: php, isset

I don't understand the difference between `isset()` and `!empty()`.

Because if a variable has been set, isn't it the same as not being empty?

Comment: Have you read the manual for both? [Here](http://www.php.net/isset) and [here](http://www.php.net/empty)

Comment: Read this http://kunststube.net/isset/ in addition. Thanks @deceze

Comment: `isset();` checks if the variable is literally set, as in the variable actually points to a value something. `empty();` checks if the value the variable points to contains anything.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**ISSET** checks the variable to see if it has been set. In other words, it checks to see if the variable is any value except NULL or not assigned a value. `ISSET` returns `TRUE` if the variable exists and has a value other than NULL. That means variables assigned a "", 0, "0", or FALSE are set, and therefore are `TRUE` for `ISSET`.

**EMPTY** checks to see if a variable is empty. Empty is interpreted as: "" (an empty string), 0 (integer), 0.0 (float)`, "0" (string), NULL, FALSE, array() (an empty array), and "$var;" (a variable declared, but without a value in a class.

Comment: " " is not empty. "" is empty.

Comment: Can you give one example where the isset is true but empty is false. Also an example where isset is false but empty is true?

Comment: @Unbreakable, If '$a=true', then `isset()` is true but `empty()` is false. If `$a=null`, then `empty()` is true but `isset()` is false

Comment: I know this is an old question, but is there a difference between `if ($variable) {}` and `if (!empty($variable)) {}` ?

Answer (score 34):

[Source :http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)This page shows the comparison of the  `empty()`,`is_null()`,`isset()`.

[image: The picture showing complete comparison here]

Answer (score 5):

The type comparison tables gives answer of all question about these operators

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 4):

And one more remark. `empty()` checks if the variable exists as well. I.e. if we perform `empty()` to the variable that wasn't declared, we don't receive an error, `empty()` returns 'true'. Therefore we may avoid `isset()` if next we need to check if the variable empty.

So

```
isset($var) && !empty($var)
```

will be equals to

```
!empty($var)
```