# Failing empty check

Tags: php, null

I have simple PHP code like this

```
$revenue = $this->dailyCounts['revenue'][$date]['net_revenue'] + (!empty($activity[$date]) ? $activity[$date] : 0) * 1000;
```

But here it is always showing warnings when the `$activity` variable is `NULL` even though I am checking for empty. I am running this inside a loop and it is always showing `undefined index` when `$activity` has null value.

Answer (score 1):

Using isset instead of empty won't solve any problem in that case.

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I guess the notice comes from $this->dailyCounts['revenue'][$date]['net_revenue']

Comment: No it is not. When I added the isset() check , it has gone. I am using this in Laravel 5

Comment: @HappyCoder: can you paste your fixed code? This shows that both do not produce warnings and give the same results: http://codepad.org/HjgrZ3RZ

Answer (score 0):

use `isset()` instead of `empty()`,

```
(!isset($activity[$date])
```

`empty()` will directly check the value, but `isset()` will see if the index is there or not.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php) and [this](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/12/18/php-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty/) for more information, its explained nicely.

Comment: with a `null` array, `isset` and `!empty` give the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$revenue = $this->dailyCounts['revenue'][$date]['net_revenue'] + ((isset($activity[$date]) && !empty($activity[$date])) ? $activity[$date] : 0) * 1000;
```