# PHP POST array with empty and isset

Tags: php

I have the following multiple checkbox selection:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit_list[]" value="apple">Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit_list[]" value="banana">Banana
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit_list[]" value="mango">Mango
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit_list[]" value="orange">Orange
```

form connects to `processor.php` via POST method. Validation:

```
if ( empty($_POST['fruit_list']) ){
    echo "You must select at least one fruit.<br>"; 
} else{
    foreach ( $_POST['fruit_list'] as $frname ){
        echo "Favourite fruit: $frname<br>";
    }
}
```

My Questions (above code works! But unclear points for me):

1. If I don't select any of checkboxes and then submit form, does `$_POST` array contain an index called `$_POST['fruit_list']` ?
2. Assuming your answer "No", then how is it possible to use `empty()` to that non existed array element? Non-existed array element means `NULL` ?
3. What is the difference using `!isset($_POST['fruit_list'])` instead of `empty()`

I understand the difference between `empty()` and `isset()` generally.

Can you explain in this context of example?

Comment: You could discover this yourself by running a little experiment.

Comment: I am a beginner. I tried already

Comment: Ok, but at least answer question number 1 for yourself. You can do that.

Comment: According to answer by @Manjeet Barnala, I understood the answer for question one very well. I printed the POST array. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If I don't select any of checkboxes and then submit form, does $_POST array contain an index called `$_POST['fruit_list']`

> No, key fruit_list does not exist

To check if key exists in array better use `array_key_exists` because if you have NULL values `isset` returns false

But in your case isset is a good way

`isset` - Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL (have any value).

`empty` - Determine whether a variable is empty (0, null, '', false, array()) but you can't understand if variable or key exists or not

For example:

```
$_POST['test'] = 0;
print 'isset check: ';
var_dump(isset($_POST['test']));
print 'empty check: ';
var_dump(empty($_POST['test']));

$_POST['test'] = null;

print 'isset NULL check: ';
var_dump(isset($_POST['test']));

print 'key exists NULL check: ';
var_dump(array_key_exists('test', $_POST));

isset check: bool(true)
empty check: bool(true)
isset NULL check: bool(false)
key exists NULL check: bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

use print_r() to print the post data..

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
if (empty($_POST['fruit_list']) ){
    echo "You must select at least one fruit.<br>"; 
}
else{
    foreach ( $_POST['fruit_list'] as $frname ){
        echo "Favourite fruit: $frname<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

If you do not select any checkbox then you will not get $_POST['fruit_list'], array index `fruit_list` does not exist in array

for difference between `isset()` and `empty()` [Visit Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583003/4018240)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

**1.** `$_POST` array does not contain `$_POST['fruit_list']`
 **2.** First answer is "**No**".A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. `empty()` does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.[see in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
 **3**. **Empty** checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc.
  **Isset** just checks if is it set, it could be anything not null. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191626/isset-and-empty-what-to-use)