# Purpose of !$ and difference b/w isset and empty?

Tags: php

1. What is the purpose of `!$` in PHP?
2. What is the difference between `isset` and `empty`?

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139 2) http://stackoverflow.com/q/20582962 simple google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `!$` means `NOT` thus if `(!$a)` and `$a == TRUE` then it is `NOT TRUE`

   Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php
2. `ISSET` returns `TRUE` if the variable exists and has a value other than `NULL` 
   `EMPTY` checks to see if a variable is empty. 
    Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
               http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Wonderful reply