# mysql_real_escape_string data control

Tags: php, mysql

I'm checking my data before creating the consult.

Lines are like:

```
$valpar_sup_reg = isset($_POST["valpar_sup_reg"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['valpar_sup_reg']) : 0;
```

I just want to control in case that there aren't data on my var's to set a 0 to all of them.

But then the consult  `$valpar_sup_reg` gives me `''` instead of `0`

Okay, i've change to mysqli statements

```
$valpar_sup_reg = !empty($_POST["valpar_sup_reg"]) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn2,$_POST["valpar_sup_reg"])  : 0;
```

Thanks for all and the negatives :)

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: don't use deprecated+removed `mysql_*` . start using `Mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements`

Comment: Could just show me which is the code to use with mysqli_ statement?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'isset()' and '!empty()' in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219542/in-where-shall-i-use-isset-and-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Stop using deprecated mysql_* functions
2) isset just checks if variable is set or not & '' string will reflect true in isset function, use [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead. 
3) You must be getting empty string i.e. '' in your $_POST use below code instead

```
$valpar_sup_reg = !empty($_POST["valpar_sup_reg"]) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql_conn_link, $_POST["valpar_sup_reg"]) : 0;
```

Empty checks below for below values:
1) "" (an empty string)
2) 0 (0 as an integer)
3) 0.0 (0 as a float)
4) "0" (0 as a string)
5) NULL
6) FALSE
7) array() (an empty array)
8) $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: I'm now using mysqli But now the escape of the $_Post is getting '' instead of the data of my database.
I'd assigned the conn_link correctly.
What could be happen?

Comment: @ntzz: Did you checked your post value before & after sending it?

Comment: Okay already running thanks
Wrong state for mysqli conn, now works correctly.
I will try to change all the mysql functions to mysqli okay?

Thanks for all, and hope to dont get more negatives xD

Answer (score 0):

```
$valpar_sup_reg = !empty($_POST["valpar_sup_reg"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['valpar_sup_reg']) : 0;
```

& as Raptor commented, better use MySQLi or PDO instead.