# Handling ajax response exceptions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently handling a form with php and calling it via an ajax request, i want to handle exceptions showing a small div instead of the basic popup
so i did multiple if conditions based on the responsetext, however one of the exceptions doesnt get handled 
This exception is the empty fields exception it always shows the wrong username or pw instead

here is the ajax call

```
function sendLogin(){
    username = $('#loginEmail').val();
    password = $('#loginPassword').val();
    a = $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,
        url: '/account/login.php',
        async: false,
    });

    if(a.responseText == "LoggedIn"){
        $("#WrongPW_Error").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#Empty_Error").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#LoggedIn").fadeIn("fast");
        setTimeout(location.reload(),2200);
     }
        else if(a.responseText == "Empty_Fields") {
          //alert(a.responseText);
          $("#WrongPW_Error").fadeOut("fast");
          $("#Empty_Error").fadeIn("fast");
     }
        else if(a.responseText == "Wrong_Credentials") {
          //alert(a.responseText);
          $("#Empty_Error").fadeOut("fast");
          $("#WrongPW_Error").fadeIn("fast");
    }
}
```

and here is the php file

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo "Empty_Fields";
    die();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$hashed_pass = hash("sha512", $password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Count(email)as total, username from Users where email = :username and password= :password");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $hashed_pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $row['total'];
if($total == 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['username'];
    echo "LoggedIn";
    die();
}
else{
    echo "Wrong_Credentials";
    die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not performing the correct check in PHP to see if the POST variables are empty.

Read: [What's the difference between 'isset()' and '!empty()' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php)

```
isset($_POST['username'])
```

will return `true` if the POST parameter exists, even if its content is an empty string. You need both tests: [isset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) AND [empty](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php).

```
if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo "Missing_Param";
    die();
}

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    echo "Empty_Fields";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: I did not notice that you're using `async: false`; leaving this answer for reference. In general it's a good idea to use non-blocking calls in JS so other UI elements aren't affected.

`$.ajax` does not return anything; it's an asynchronous call that will call a function when it completes. You'll need to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  // other arguments here
  success: function(data) {
    // handle success
  },
  error: function() {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

More examples available [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `die()` on your PHP code, send an error response. Call `http_response_code(401)` (not authorized response). Second issue is that `$.ajax` doesn't return a response and `async = false` has been deprecated and should not be used. Instead, define two functions for success and failure and just set those as the `success` and `error` parameters of your AJAX request.

```
    $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,
         url: '/account/login.php',
         async: false,
         success: successFunction,
         error: errorFunction
     });

    function successFunction(response){
        $("#WrongPW_Error").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#Empty_Error").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#LoggedIn").fadeIn("fast");
        setTimeout(location.reload(),2200);

    }
    function errorFunction(response){
            $("#WrongPW_Error").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#Empty_Error").fadeIn("fast");
     }
```