# Is checking with !empty() functions enough to prevent notice and warning message in PHP 7+?

Tags: php, function, isset

After all this time I have been checking on a variable with both `isset() && ! empty()` function as following.

```
if ( isset($my_arr['myh_index']) && ! empty($my_arr['myh_index']) ) { ... }
```

Because I though I have read somewhere that `isset()` function only checks if a variable is set, it will also return true even a variable contains null or an empty string. That's why I also check with `!empty()` function to make sure.

Today, I found out that the difference is that `!empty()` function does not generate any warning or notice message.

Can I just only check with `if ( ! empty($my_arr['my_index']) ) { ... }` to prevent

- 'Notice (8): Undefined variable'
- 'Warning (2): Illegal string offset'
- 'Notice (8): Undefined index'

?

Comment: They're not the same, and have never been the same, not even in PHP7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php

Comment: There is an answer to the difference between isset() and empty(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php. And far as i know there were no changes in PHP 7.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/qVCnV see there

Comment: See [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99d5ebe0b55945f751b960b31f4ea5a1eebd6246)

Comment: `""`, `0` and `false` are set, but empty

Comment: I just edited my question because it was duplicated.

Comment: `if (!empty($my_arr['my_index']))` will return `true` (not empty) if `empty($my_arr['my_index'])` is set **and** doesn't contain any of those : `0`, `false`, `""`, `"0"`, `array()` or `[]` (empty array)

Comment: For more information, [Read That Fine Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (especially the *return values* part)

Comment: I do understand about the return value the `empty()` function returns. But I just want to ask if `! empty()` function can surely prevent the warning and notice message mentioned in my question above. Because all this time I though `empty()` function did not prevent such message. That's why I have been using both `if( isset() && !empty() )` which seems not to be necessary.