# php login form trim Undefined index Error

Tags: php, sql-server, authentication, trim

I typed the correct user and the wrong user. I get this message:

> Notice: Undefined index: username and Undefined index: password.

I'm getting invalid user input error in the input code.

Line 18 and 23 are returning the `Undefined index` message.

Incorrect user input is written instead of input in input section.

How to fix this problem?
I have examined many topics.

**This PHP Code**

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require_once "../../config.php";

        if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
            header("location: ../../index.php");
            exit;
        }

        $username = " ";
        $password = " ";
        $username_err = " ";
        $password_err =  " "; 

        
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

            if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
                $username_err = "Lütfen kullanıcı adınızı giriniz.";
            } else {
                $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            }
            if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
                $password_err = "Lütfen şifrenizi giriniz.";
            } else{
                $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
            }

            if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
                $tsql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM [ARAC_TAKIP].[dbo].[KULLANİCİLAR] 
                WHERE username = :username ";
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($tsql)){
                $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

                if($stmt->execute()){
                    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                        if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                            $id = $row["id"];
                            $username = $row["username"];
                            $hashed_password = $row["password"];
                            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                                session_start();
                                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                                header("location: ../../index.php");
                        } else{
                            $password_err = "Hatalı şifre girdiniz !!";
                        }
                    }
                } else{$username_err = "Kullanıcı adı bulunamadı.!!";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Hata oluştu. Yeniden giriş yapınız.";
            }
            unset($stmt);
        }
    }
    unset($pdo);
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't use `trim()` inside `empty()` and still have the benefits of it checking the field not being set.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP docs are saying, that [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) needs a variable as parameter. `trim()` as a method won't work with `empty()`.  You should use [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if the POST variable is declared:

```
if(!isset($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $username_err = "Lütfen kullanıcı adınızı giriniz.";
} else {
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}
if(!isset($_POST["password"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $password_err = "Lütfen şifrenizi giriniz.";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}
```

Comment: [What's the difference between 'isset()' and '!empty()' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php).  Also what if `$_POST["username"]` is `" "`, this is not empty but is set.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP Documentation, the `empty()` function receives only a variable as a parameter. This means you cannot use `empty("Data")`. You need to set the parameter as a variable before and call the function, as this example:

```
$foo = trim(" Test");
$isEmpty = empty($foo);
```

Best regards!